# APEX how to create a page that allows you to create username and passwords for a single user

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, writeablebitmapex

Been trying to create mock website of a sort, but can't seem to determine which page and page type is required in order for any new user to create a username and password, email etc...

Is it a feasible task on Apex? Or do i need to go to another program such as php?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please submit a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Apex makes sense if you're storing those information into a database.

The simplest option to do that - if it is *you* who will be doing it for all users - would be a **report with form on table**. Wizard creates an interactive report (which is used to view data, lets you navigate to details and update/delete those information) or create new users. The form does exactly that: updates/deletes & creates new rows.

If you'd let everyone do it for themselves, then it is a **form on a table**.

When you click the "Create page" button, follow the Wizard which will create everything for you. Maybe it won't look perfect, but it'll work. Then you can make it *fancy*.